# How do I join tables from two different PDO object?

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, pdo

I don't know how must i do to join tables from two different PDO object. I hope all of you can help me to solve this problem. I really thanks for your respons.

```
$dbsql = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbpenggajian', $user='root', $pass='');

$dbaccess = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=D:\\Kepegawaian Arto Moro\BACK_UP_ABSENSI\TJ_Main_Data.mdb; Uid=userName;Pwd=everyday;");
```

and this is my experiment code

```
$acc=$dbaccess+$dbsql->query("SELECT *
                    FROM dbaccess.HR_Personnel as h
                    RIGHT JOIN dbaccess.TA_Record_Info a
                    ON h.ID=a.Per_ID
                    INNER JOIN dbsql.pegawai_tetap as p
                    on h.Per_Code=p.nip ;");
    while($k=$acc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

but still error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

please help me. thanks

Comment: you can't simultaneously query 2 different database like this: $acc=$dbaccess+$dbsql->query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's impossible, of course.

You have to import your ODBC table in mysql first.